# Adds-on for building a online assessment/application system

Tags: ee2, forms, users, groups

I am new to EE and plan to build an online assessment/application site. In short, users will be able to enter basic information and get a link to a proper online form/downloadable pdf which they should fill in and submit/upload later. Once the form is submitted,an admin will perform as the grader to grade their forms and make the decision(accept or redo).

In detail, current requirements are:

1. There should be multiple user groups, like different teams, all users in the same team should represent a single team, and share the same team information (like contact info, teamID).
2. Interactive form, which direct users to right online form/pdf based on their input
3. There should be a progress bar to remind users that how many info they still need to enter, how many form to fill&submit and a overall progress.
4. Email notification when a form is submitted or graded (I think this can be done by the built-in functions?).

To some extent, this site will function as a LMS site, so I am researching that if available adds-on like QUIZ4EE or Polls can be used as a platform for this.

I was mainly doing WordPress and Drupal, this will be my first EE site, so please forgive my ignorance and any input will be appreciated.